# RFID (or other) - Proximity Detector

Tags: rfid, counter, detection

I am trying to detect how often 2 animals 'interact'. Say I have 4 cats, I am trying to work out how often each of the cats interact with each other.

I have considered using RFID tags attached to their collars. Ideally this would mean that every time each cat came close to another cat each tag would 'see' each other and that count would be recorded. So for example over the course of a week I would be able to see how many 'counts' each cat had with any other. Is this possible with RFID or is there another technology to do this I am unaware of.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably cheaper to put a GPS recorder on the beasties.  Record where they go, then use software to look for times when both are close together.  Else, you are looking at building something with transmitter+receiver for recognition and a data logger of some kind - in a water proof, cat proof box that is "cat portable." GPS loggers for cats are commercially available - and cheap.  As a benefit, it becomes easier to detect encounters between multiple cats.

Answer (score 1):

An RFID tag is, in its basic form, a passive device until it is subjected to a localized field (usually magnetic) whereupon the tag's power circuits collect enough energy to form a supply voltage that can activate a small microprocessor and it either modulates the impacting magnetic field (so that the base station can determine the codewords sent by the tag) or it generates an RF field that the base station can receive.

Some tags have batteries but, for the most part they are passive and don't ping an output field that can be detected by a similar tag.

If you want to ping a field you are going to need far more power/energy than that available to a tag and the batteries won't last that long. However, it's not impossible to get several weeks life from a D cell I would imagine - it would need to be carefully designed and quite possibly use infra red pings to see if another animal was close by.

You can locally store "meetings" between the cats in each "tag" and somehow download that information when a cat approaches a base station of some type. This could use regular tag technology I reckon.